# Sending to checked checkbox which is linked to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I'm new to coding such as Javascript and PHP, I need to create a form that will be hosted on a site which on a submit will send an email dependent on which checkbox is ticked, the different checkboxes will go to different emails, would I need to use a PHP post for this and is there any need for Jquery at all? or could I just use PHP? would love the help. Thank you

```
<?php  
    $mail1 = "test@test.com";
    $mail2 = "test2@test.com";
    $mail3 = "test3@test.com";
    if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
        $mail1 = $_POST["MainCB"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
        $mail2 = $_POST["ITCB"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
        $mail3 = $_POST["CateCB"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $MainCB = $_POST['MainCB'];
    $ITCB = $_POST['ITCB'];
    $CateCB = $_POST['CateCB'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . $MainCB . " " . $ITCB . " " . $CateCB;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form submission</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
            Last Name:  <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
            Maintenance:<input type="checkbox" id="MainCB"><br>
            IT:         <input type="checkbox" id="ITCB"><br>
            Catering:   <input type="checkbox" id="CateCB"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, you have to try yourself first.

Comment: So far I have got this but its so wrong;

Comment: please edit your original question to put code in and do not use an answer for that

Comment: I have updated what I have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form like this

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <input name="checkbox1" value="email1@yahoo.com" type="checkbox"></input>
    <input name="checkbox2" value="email2@gmail.com" type="checkbox"></input>
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

And in your mailing script you can retrieve the checkbox value.

```
    if(isset($_POST["checkbox1"])) {
        $mail1 = $_POST["checkbox1"];
    }
```

Comment: Is the mail.php going to be a separate document?

Comment: Your mailing script is where you check for isset($_POST["checkbox1"]) and checkbox2. It can be the same php file or a different one.

Comment: Would I then need another script that on submit would send that form data into an email, such as using

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $to = "example@example.com"; // this is your Email address
  // $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $subject = "Form submission";
  $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
  $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['MainCB'];
  }

Comment: But then I don't get how it would know who to send it to

Comment: unless the person who I send it to is a variable which I get from the checkbox script?

Comment: In your mailing script where you check for submit for example you can check for the checkbox1 and checkbox2 values. And instead of hardcoding the $to = "example@example.com" you replace it with the checkbox value.

Comment: <?php  
 $mail1 = "test@test.com";
 $mail2 = "test2@test.com";
 $mail3 = "test3@test.com";
 if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
        $mail1 = $_POST["MainCB"];
    }
 if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
        $mail2 = $_POST["ITCB"];
    }
 if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
        $mail3 = $_POST["CateCB"];
    }
?>

Comment: Could I do this instead? ^

Comment: Or would I need else

Comment: and if multiple are checked would It send to those that are checked

Comment: Ahh I need to get all the form data in the email, so would I need that other script to check for a submit and include the if's you sent me and just get rid of the $to

Comment: If you check for the checkboxes like this:

When the first checkbox is indeed checked you add that address to your $to variable.

    if(isset($_POST["checkbox1"])) {
        $to = $_POST["checkbox1"];
    }

If the second checkbox is also checked you can concatenate that email to your $to variable aswell if you seperate the emails with a comma.
    if(isset($_POST["checkbox2"])) {
        $to .= "," . $_POST["checkbox2"];
    }

Comment: Im confused with that last one but i added what I have done so far with your help and have no idea if im doing it right

Comment: You nearly got it but in your mailing script give your checkbox all the name attributes with them. For example <input type="checkbox" id="MainCB" name="MainCB" value="something@gmail.com"><br> because the $_POST looks for the name and not the ID and also a value attribute which should be the email.

Comment: Is that all I need? so If I fill out my form a bit more with more questions and get back to you hopefully all should be working haha

Comment: Also sorry for being a noob, first time using stackoverflow as well :/

Comment: That should be all you need pretty much, No problem we all got to start somewhere.:)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, its great to have an awesome member of the coding community :)

Comment: No problem :) If you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: <?php  
 if(isset($_POST["MainCB"])) {
  $to = $_POST["test@test.com"]; 
    }
 if(isset($_POST["ITCB"])) {
        $to = $_POST["test@test.com"];
    }
 if(isset($_POST["CateCB"])) {
        $to = $_POST["test@test.com"];
    }
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $to = "";
 $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
 $MainCB = $_POST['MainCB'];
 $ITCB = $_POST['ITCB'];
 $CateCB = $_POST['CateCB'];
 $subject = "Form submission";
 $message = $full_name . " " . $MainCB . " " . $ITCB . " " . $CateCB;
 mail($to,$subject,$message);
 include 'mail.php';
 }
?>

Comment: hi Richard, what would I put as my $to variable as I have just blank "" and dont know if it needs to link

Comment: You want the email from your checkbox so you need to tell $to to be the value of the checkbox like $to = $_POST["MainCB"]; this will store the email of the Main checkbox in the $to variable.